# How can I select non-existing column from sub-select?

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

```
select * from cust
where cust_id in
(select cust_id from acc_co
where objectum = 'EXIST');
```

In the **acc_co** table there is no **cust_id** column. But when I run the select, it has result. But how?

(The result of this select and the row number of the **cust** table are same.)

Comment: You wrote a Correlated Subquery which results in a comparison similar to `cust_id=cust_id`

Comment: If `cust_id` was in the subquery's `where` clause e.g. `where objectum = cust_id`, would you still find this strange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that you don't use aliases so the DBMS thinks that the `cust_id` is a column of the first table `cust`. Since you are using a correlated subquery the data in the subquery can be recognized as so as data of an inner nor as outer table data. This case is ok not only for `Oracle` but for any RDBMS. To avoid this ambiguity please use aliases in correlated subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

prefixing the columns should answer this one for you:

```
select * from cust c
where c.cust_id in
(select a.cust_id from acc_co a
where a.objectum = 'EXIST');
```

VS

```
select * from cust c
where c.cust_id in
(select c.cust_id from acc_co a
where a.objectum = 'EXIST');
```

- You will notice that the first version fails and the second one shows the behaviour you witnessed (you get the full `cust` table).
- The first version tries to do what you thought you did with your query: select a non-existing column.
- The second version shows how oracle actually interpreted your query.
- The topic to google for is **table alias**, there are many pages out there that explain them well
- It's generally good practice to use aliases to avoid such situations
- When a column name only appears in one of the tables of the query, then oracle allows you to not use aliases like in your query.
- As soon as a column appears in more than one table oracle will throw an error: `ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined`

HTH

Comment: I see it, and thanks, but why select all rows of CUST table, when I run the original select?

Comment: @APC because lunch was ready ^^ and I still wanted to provide something to play with to OP quickly and then write some info later in case he still had questions. but ty to you for adding the scoping info. kr

Comment: @APC Should I add your explanation to the answer now via edit or shall we leave this as it is with your explanation being in the comment? What's the procedure here on SO?